# Spider-Man comic with several villains in it

Tags: story-identification, marvel, spider-man

A long time ago I read a Spider-Man comic of which I'm trying to find the name. One memorable quote was from a villain who was complaining that he "had millions, lost millions". Also, there was a dinosaur-like villain who broke into an aquarium and terrorized the people, but then picked up a fish who fell out of its tank and put it back in water, saying, "there is no reason for a non-human creature to suffer". At the end of it, it showed Doctor Octopus welding himself a new set of metal arms. I think Spider-Man was captured and restrained the entire comic.

Anybody know what I'm talking about?

UPDATE:

Thunderforge was right! I was thinking of "Spider-Man - Lethal Foes Of Spider-Man: Hate Is A Many Splendored Thing". Here is the page I was referring to with Beetle
[image: Lethal Foes of Spider-Man, vol. 2, page 5]
This was page 5.

Comment: Was the millions a reference to money or people? Knowing if the villain was rich might narrow it down. Also, do you remember anything else about the villain? Male or female? Super-powered? Also, when did you read this comic?

Comment: @Thunderforge money. He was male and I believe he had a hover board, similar to what the green goblin used. I don't think he had super powers.  I think he had brown hair, stubble, and lived in an apartment. I red the comic about 15 years ago so my recall may be slightly off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best guess is that this is [*The Lethal Foes of Spider-Man*](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lethal_Foes_of_Spider-Man_Vol_1), a four-issue series from 1993.

One thing that stands out in your description is that there are three villains present. This is unusual as most Spider-Man comics focus on one, maybe two villains. Also unusual is the fact that Spider-Man isn't present for most of the comic, despite being the protagonist.

You mentioned that there was a dinosaur-guy. That could only be [Stegron](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Vincent_Stegron_(Earth-616)). Fortunately, he isn't too common of a Spider-Man villain and has only appeared a few dozen times. The only time that he appeared in a comic with Doctor Octopus was in *The Lethal Foes of Spider-Man*. There were other villains that appeared as well, which explains the presence of a third villain.

The villain who had made and lost millions is harder to say. Including your comments, it sounds like perhaps it was [Harry Osborn](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Harold_Osborn_(Earth-616)) since he was wealthy, had the Green Goblin glider, and to my knowledge lived alone. However, he wasn't in this comic, so if it was him, then you're probably mixing your memories of two comics. The [Vulture](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Adrian_Toomes_(Earth-616)) was in the comic though, and had the ability to fly through his special suit (perhaps confusing flying with the hoverboard?), but to my knowledge he has never had stubble. He's not known to be rich, but I suppose his life of crime might have amounted to him stealing and subsequently losing millions.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to confirm whether or not this is the comic you are after. Surprisingly, I was unable to find a single description of the plot of the comic anywhere online. Also, I don't own it, and it's not on Marvel Unlimited, so I can't check myself.

Still, this seems like the most likely candidate given that it's the only comic containing both Stegron and Doctor Octopus, and a comic focusing on the villains seems like it would probably find an excuse to get Spider-Man out of the picture.

Comment: I think it may have been issue #2 http://www.comicvine.com/lethal-foes-of-spider-man-2-hate-is-a-many-splendo/4000-94944/ who is the villain shown in the top right corner of the front cover? I think that's who said "had millions, lost millions".

Comment: @Celeritas That villain is [Beetle](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Abner_Jenkins_(Earth-616)), who I admit I don't know a lot about. Here is [a picture of him without his armor](http://www.byrnerobotics.com/forum/uploads/RayDyas/2007-03-06_234823_Abe_Jenkins.jpg). Also, it does seem that he can fly (funny how Wikipedia prominently says that, but the Marvel wiki doesn't).

Comment: Found it, if interested I uploaded image. Now I'm interested in what he was referring to when he said he had millions of dollars.

Comment: @Celeritas well the Beetle was the organizer behind the Sinister Syndicate which was an occasionally successful supervillain mercenary group. See ASM 281 & 282, and the Deadly Foes of Spider-Man 4-issue limited series from 1991. It's been years since I read the latter but I think I recall that part of the premise was that the group was living a life of ease due to their ill-gotten gains.